# Easier way to add existing project to project group in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe8

I am using Delphi XE8 and I have a project group containing lots of projects.  Even though the group is already big, I sometimes still need to add existing projects to it.

Now the only way you can add an existing project to a group in Delphi (to the best of my knowledge) is using the group item's context menu in the project group tree view:

[image: Project group context menu]

When the group is big, like in my case, the project list in the tree view could be scrolled down, so that the group item, which is always at the top, would be out of view.  In order to add an existing project to my group, therefore, I would have to scroll up the tree view in order to right-click on the group item.

In contrast, the Add New Project command can be invoked in two ways: from the same context menu as above and using a speed button on the Project Manager's toolbar:

[image]

The toolbar is always in view, which makes adding new projects very easy.  I would like to have the same kind of convenience for my scenario, but the Project Manager toolbar does not appear to be customisable.  Is there a way, perhaps using third-party tools, to edit the toolbar in order to add a button for adding an existing project?  Or maybe a different method to make the command more accessible?

Comment: Apart from drag & drop option, you can activate project manager using mouse or `[Ctrl+Alt+F11]` and hit `[Home]` key. Adding projects to group isn't something that one does frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Add existing project* command is available for customizing one of the IDE toolbars.

Comment: Thanks, this looks closest to what I had in mind, even though other suggestions were also good.

Answer (score 4):

You can drag'n'drop a project file in the project explorer and it is added to the group! Or you just doubleclick/open the project to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add new or existing project to your project group from Delphi Project menu. Using the contex menu that pops up when you right click on project group is not the only way to do so.

[image: Add Existing Project command in Project menu]

Or you can use these commands to start a new project group when no project is opened in the IDE since these commands are always available.

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe a different method to make the command more accessible?

The shortest way - to my knowledge - is this keyboard sequence:

```
Ctrl+Alt+F11             (Show project manager, and put focus there)
Home                     (Move selection to the name of project group)
Win-Context-menu-key     (Same as right-click: show context popup menu)
A                        (Add existing project)
```

If you have a cheap keyboard without a menu key, you can use Shift+F10 instead of Win-Context-Menu-Key.

Comment: And if you have a cheap keyboard without a menu key, you can use Shift+F10 instead.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand answer updated with that info. Thanks.